# python Django reportlab can't find msyh.ttf file

Tags: python, django, reportlab

When I use

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('msyh', 'msyh.ttf'))
```

I meet a bug that is

```
reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts.TTFError: Can't open file "msyh.ttf"
```

However, if I download the msyh.ttf file and use an absolute path like

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('msyh', r'C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\msyh.ttf'))
```

It works.

How could I fix this bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solving my problem by installing msyh.ttf in my venv directory...

Comment: i already install on my local pc (developent server) but system still find .ttf file in temp folder.